# How to get right text character index using foreach in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get character indexes using forach loop.

```
   var text = "aaab";

   foreach (var item in text)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf(item));
   }
```

The output is : 0 0 0 3

But I expected : 0 1 2 3

so my other operations are going wrong. Why indexOf()  method does not get right index?

Comment: [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0) return the first element who match the item. This is why the output is three `0`, because `a` is the first. Into the loop, you are looping through 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'. The index where there is an 'a' is the first one, so the output is `0 0 0 3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## String.IndexOf Method
>
> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string within this instance. The method returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof

Eventhough there are 3 occurences of "a", the first occurence of "a" will always be 0.
In this case, your `foreach`-loop is equivalent to writing:

```cs
var text = "aaab";
Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf("a"));
Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf("a"));
Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf("a"));
Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf("b"));
```

But the method does have overloads that let you specify a `startIndex` to start searching.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with indexes, why not switching from `foreach` to `for` loop?

```
var text = "aaab";

for (int index = 0; index < text.Length; ++index) {
  char item = text[index];

  // from now on, you have both item (as in foreach) and index

  //TODO: paste relevant code here 
}
```

If you want to obtain all character ocurrencies (say, all indexes of `'a'`) within given string, I suggest implementing a simple enumeration, e.g. (let it be an extension method)

```
 public static partial class StringExtensions {
   public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf(this string value, char toFind) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      yield break;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
      if (value[i] == toFind)
        yield return i;
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
var text = "aaab";

foreach (var index in text.IndexesOf('a'))
{
  // 0 1 2 - indexes of 'a' within "aaab"    
  Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IndexOf() function show the first occurrence of a item. in your case, 'a' is in the 0 position 3 times.

To run as you desire, the code need this:

```
var text = "aaab";
var i=0;
foreach (var item in text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.IndexOf(item,i));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be best to make another index variable since `IndexOf()` only returns the index of the first occurrence of the char.

```cs
var text = "aaab";
int index = 0;
foreach(var item in text){
  Console.WriteLine(index);
  index++;
}
```

Comment: While this may produce the expected output, it does not actually find the index of the char in `text`. Please re-read the original question.